# In EWS how to know how many items in a folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

For example, how do I know how many email items in inbox folder?
FindItemsResults findResults = service.FindItems(
            WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
            new ItemView(10,0));
The above code only lists first 10 items, how to know how many items in inbox folder, so that I can calculate how many pages with 10 items in one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Folder.TotalCount Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.totalcount%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx)?